# Where can I find economic multilateral treaty data?

Tags: data-request, economics, global

I am doing a project on multilateral treaties and am having trouble finding a data set on multilateral economic treaties. I am looking for data with signature and/or ratification dates. Does anyone know of a dataset or website that holds this? Here is an [example webpage](https://treaties.un.org/pages/showDetails.aspx?objid=08000002800ade6c) with the necessary data but for only 1 treaty:

So far I have only found good aggregated information on bilateral or plurilateral treaties. The World Trade Organisation's Regional Trade Agreements' database is a [good example of this](http://rtais.wto.org/UI/PublicMaintainRTAHome.aspx)

Comment: could you provide links to example of the type of data for bilateral treaties that you would like to find for multilateral treaties?

Comment: updated to incorporate suggestion